# How save multiple js objects in SessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I'm trying to send objects in a sessionStorage with a button calls ".buttonClipboard". But only send one. I want send more objects from the table.

This is the code:

```
$('#buttonsDocumentation .buttonClipboard').on('click', function(){
    clipboard = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("clipboard"));
    if($.inArray(rowSelected[0], clipboard) < 0){
        if(clipboard == null){
            clipboard = [];
        }
        clipboard.push(rowSelected[0]);
        sessionStorage.setItem('clipboard', JSON.stringify(clipboard));
    }
    testClipboard();
});
```

How is it?

PD: rowSelected[0] is like id from object row.

Comment: You should check for `clipboard == null` *before* calling `$.inArray().` Otherwise you'll get an error from `$.inArray()`.

Comment: Also, `JSON.parse()` will get an error if the session storage item isn't set yet. You should check if `getItem()` returns something before trying to parse it.

Comment: Other than those problems, I don't see any reason why this doesn't send all the objects to session storage.

Comment: @Barmar The code send the objects one by one, not two in two o three in three. When I selected a document and another, the clipboard have two documents. But I want select multiples rows for send to Clipboard

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple selected rows to the clipboard, you need to send all of them in `push()`, not just `selectedRow[0]`. You can use spread syntax for this:

```
clipboard.push(...selectedRow);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to mutate the clipboard object, you can use `const newClipboard = [...clipboard, ...selectedRow]`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply. I have proved it but it not make I want :(  Send the folder parent with the document selected from row but not send the others elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative, but only works in one table (tabDocument) instead of two (tabSearch):

```
$('#buttonsDocumentacion .botonClipboard').on('click', function(){
    var idsClip=[];
    if(clipboard = tableDocument.rows('.selected').data()){
        for(var i=0; i<clipboard.length; i++){
            idsClip.push(clipboard[i][0]);
        }   
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('clipboard', JSON.stringify(idsClip));
    compruebaClipboard();
})
```